# Missing: 'NgxWebstorageModule@5.0.0 when deploying Angular to Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment

I couldn't find almost any results about this one, the application works fine on localhost.
When pushing to Heroku I got this error

```
Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: 'NgxWebstorageModule@5.0.0
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!
```

Things I tried:

-Remove the package-lock.json.

-Reinstalling node modules.

Here is my package.json file:

```
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^7.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "'NgxWebstorageModule": "5.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

When I try to reinstall node modules, I have to delete the 'NgxWebstorageModule": "5.0.0" in devDependencies because I keep getting an error ''NgxWebstorageModule@5.0.0' is not in the npm registry.

Comment: You have a typo: `"'NgxWebstorageModule"`

Comment: The correct name of the package is: `ngx-webstorage`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage

Comment: Brandon, can you explain where is the typo please

Comment: There's an extra single quote before the word, however that package name is incorrect.

Comment: You actually shouldn't need to list that as a dependency at all.

Comment: Ok I got you now, but I already removed that line and repushed to heroku and still had the same thing "npm ERR! Missing: 'NgxWebstorageModule@5.0.0"

Comment: I'm not sure why that would fail. NgxWebstorageModule is part of the ngx-webstorage package. I don't have any experience with that package. I just saw the typo in the package.json then went to NPM to see if the name of the package was correct or not.